# gdal_fillnodata strange artifacts

Tags: raster, gdal, interpolation, nodata

I'm seeing an odd artifact when using `gdal_fillnodata.py`.

I have a raster[image: Source image]

(purple is no data, white and black are two different numeric values).

Using a mask exactly corresponding to the no data pixels (i.e. all no data pixels are set to 0 in the mask raster, and all others set to 1) when running the following command:

`gdal_fillnodata.py -md 20 -mask path_to_mask.tif path_to_raster.tif  output.tif`

I get the following output:
[image: Result Image]

The thing I am confused about is the rectangular area of slightly lighter pixels to the bottom left of the image - it seems very uniform, and I can't see anything obvious in the source raster that would cause that. It does become less prominent when smoothing is used, but the anomaly is still there.

Has anyone seem similar behaviour, or can explain it?

Source image: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xyGZE3alZxvutHGb_F7zs-bOjFAZQZis/view?usp=drive_link

Mask image: https://drive.google.com/file/d/14H9ZIb29dZ3j-dxkGfXONVgByZn5TsY1/view?usp=drive_link

Result image: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Sb4bQv7hDfUDfziQtpgVKYKvrkotPghE/view?usp=drive_link